# Reloading page and modal without closing modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

Is it possible to reload page and informations Inside a modal without closing the modal.
Context : 
multiphase form with session at the end of phase 1 which I would like to retrieve in phase 2.
Sorry for my disastrous English. I hope my problem is clearly explained.
Thanks.
My preview is to retrieve my session datas in the modal form phase 2.

Comment: Do you want to reload the entire page .. would reloading the modal be enough ?

Comment: You could make modal open again after refresh, based on session info...

Comment: the sine qua non condition if to retrieve my session in phase 2. I find my session with echo on the page when reload. that's why I'm searching in this direction. bur may be, it exist others solutons

Comment: reload page means that you can use technique like `pjax`

Comment: I've tried to refind my data with ajax and json but the format isn't the one I need.:  two  datas on "php echo" and on into input hiddent

Comment: If you only want to reload the modal, user the .load function on your modal element ...

Comment: ivn --> I don't want the modal close.

Comment: @Evane Let me try to ask you one more time. Is it enough that you only reload the MODAL!

Comment: @DTH yes it's enough if I retrieve my session datas

Comment: Impossible for me to find the way.

Comment: Even searching for a CLEAR tuto ...